# using Python functools.partial SyntaxError: can't assign to function call

Tags: python-3.x, python-3.5

I'm getting this error. How to fix this? Am I missing something about using partials?

> get_make_models(rows) = partial(groupby_attrs, attributes=['Year', 'Make'])
>
> > SyntaxError: can't assign to function call

```
import itertools
from functools import partial

def get_keyfunc(attributes):

    def keyfunc(row):
        """
            returns row values for attribues joined with '-'
        """
        values_arr = [row[attribute] for attribute in attributes]
        return '-'.join(values_arr)

    return keyfunc

def groupby_attrs(attributes, rows):
    keyfunc = get_keyfunc(attributes)
    data = sorted(rows, key=keyfunc)
    return itertools.groupby(data, key=keyfunc)

get_year_make_models = partial(groupby_attrs, attributes=['Year', 'Make', 'Model'])
get_make_models(rows) = partial(groupby_attrs, attributes=['Year', 'Make'])
```

Comment: May I know the reason for the down vote? I waster one hour on this issue. It may look trivial in hindsight now but are we saying that it's really that obvious?

Answer (score 0):

Found it, I was looking only at the right end of the line. On the left, you can see the variable is a function call. Sorry for the mistake.

`get_make_models(rows) = partial(groupby_attrs, attributes=['Year', 'Make'])`

```
               ^^^^^^
```